# package.json changes formatting on npm i

Tags: npm, npm-install

Whenever I do `npm i` in the console, package.json reformats from

```
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
        "development": ["last 1 chrome version", "last 1 safari version"]
    }
```

to

```
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
```

There is no IDE open or involved. Only me and my console. Why is this keep happening to me?